# How do I get just the list of names from a command?

Tags: powershell

That title may have been a little bit confusing because I don't know any better way to say it.

Anyways, I have this code `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize`

that shows me all of the programs installed on my PC.

I'm familiar with the ., but I'm a little bit confused on how to get just the names of the programs in the list. Any help?

Comment: (Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*").DisplayName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include just the name in the `Select-Object` command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two registry keys which contain programs installed.

Registry key to get installed Apps: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

and Registry key for 32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

You can create a ForEach loop to get the dot property 'DisplayName' of each app then add to an array before sorting for unique names
$array = $row = $Location = $Reg = $null

```
    $Location =  'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
                 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    
    ForEach ($Reg in $Location) {
    $row = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $Reg).DisplayName
    $array = $array + $row
    }
    $array | Sort-Object -Unique
```

There may be other registry locations where a program has been installed and is only available to specific user(s) other than all users or current user.

Answer (score 0):

All you can get are the values present in the registry. You can a list of the possible values with

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | gm
```

Normally you will NOT find a name of the executable but only the DisplayName. You may look at DisplayIcon to see the executable but this is not standard.

Comment: This pulls up a list of all the methods and note properties of System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject not the list of installed programs.

Comment: Yes, it shows a list of available note properties. From this list it should be clear that the name of an executable could not be found reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but I want to add my two cents.

I would use something like the one from Antony's comment:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*").DisplayName
```

But I will use HKLM: PSDrive, I think this is the simplest method:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*").DisplayName
```

However this is only one half of the picture, the mere existence of Wow6432Node means that you are using a 64-bit Windows, because it will only exist in 64-bit Windows.

Wow64 means Windows (32-bit) on Windows 64-bit, it is a compatibilty layer that enables x86 programs to run on x86-64 Windows, the x86 programs are installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\ and their libraries are in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and registry keys stored in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node, while the 64-bit programs are installed in C:\Program Files\ and use dlls in C:\Windows\System32 and registry keys are subkeys of HKLM\Software, so to get program names of both x86 and x64 software use the following two commands:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*").DisplayName
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*").DisplayName
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Getting List of Installed Applications that Matches Add/Remove Programs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529209/getting-list-of-installed-applications-that-matches-add-remove-programs-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

---

***Powershell Script :***

```
OS_Architecture = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
if($OS_Architecture -eq 'x86') 
{
    #write-host '32-bit'
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}
else
{
    #write-host '64-bit'
    $key = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
}

Get-ItemProperty $Key |
        Select-Object DisplayName |
            Format-Table –AutoSize
```

---

Or simply with command line you can use `WMIC`

```
wmic product get name
```